# org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: properties is not a valid field name

Tags: java, apache-kafka, jms, apache-kafka-connect, weblogic12c

If there is any reference project or code using open source to send Kafka message to JMS queue, that would be helpful.
I tried calling below code in junit,

```
private TextMessage getTextMessage(SinkRecord sinkRecord) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Processing Record: key={} value={}"+sinkRecord.key()+""+sinkRecord.value());
        final String payload = sinkRecord.value().toString();
        final TextMessage textMessage = webLogicJmsSession.session().createTextMessage(payload);
        textMessage.setStringProperty("KafkaTopic", sinkRecord.topic());
        textMessage.setIntProperty("KafkaPartition", sinkRecord.kafkaPartition());
        textMessage.setLongProperty("KafkaOffset", sinkRecord.kafkaOffset());
        Object key = sinkRecord.key();
        try {
            Schema keySchema = sinkRecord.keySchema();
            Struct keyStruct = (Struct) key;
            //Struct jmsStruct = keyStruct.getStruct("jms");
            Struct jmsProperties = keyStruct.getStruct("properties");
            keySchema
                .field("properties")
                .schema()
                .fields()
                .forEach(field -> {
                    String value = jmsProperties.getString(field.name());
                    try {
                        textMessage.setStringProperty(field.name(), value);
                    } catch (JMSException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
            Struct jmsHeaders = keyStruct.getStruct("headers");
            textMessage.setJMSCorrelationID(jmsHeaders.getString("JMSCorrelationID"));
            final String jmsReplyTo = jmsHeaders.getString("JMSReplyTo");
            if (jmsReplyTo != null)
                textMessage.setJMSReplyTo(webLogicJmsSession.session().createQueue(jmsReplyTo));
            textMessage.setJMSCorrelationID(jmsHeaders.getString("JMSCorrelationID"));
            textMessage.setJMSType(jmsHeaders.getString("JMSType"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return textMessage;
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Here is junit code

```
Schema dowSchema = SchemaBuilder.array(Schema.STRING_SCHEMA).build();
              Schema airingToItemSchema = SchemaBuilder.struct()
                      .field("dow", dowSchema)
                      .build();
              Schema airingToSchema = SchemaBuilder.array(airingToItemSchema).build();
              Schema rootSchema = SchemaBuilder.struct()
                      .field("airingTo", airingToSchema).build();

              Struct item = new Struct(airingToItemSchema)
              .put("dow", Collections.singletonList("SATURDAY"));
              Struct rootStruct = new Struct(rootSchema)
              .put("airingTo", Collections.singletonList(item));

              SinkRecord sinkRecord4 =  new SinkRecord("test",0,dowSchema,rootStruct,schema,struct,1234L);
              webLogicJmsSinkTask.put(Arrays.asList(sinkRecord4));
```

But it throws below error,

Processing Record: key={} value={}Struct{airingTo=[Struct{dow=[SATURDAY]}]}Struct{first_name=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,last_name=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,email_address=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: properties is not a valid field name

Comment: Well, looking at your error, `properties` is indeed not a field name of that Struct

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer. But not sure how to get jms properties from strut object. If you know any other open source connector which I can use.

Comment: Kafka Connect Struct doesn't have anything to do with JMS, so I'm not sure what properties you're referring to. It appears you're getting some Struct and Schema object out of some SinkRecord, so you can print or set up a breakpoint there to see all information that is available. For example - your error log says the key Struct is empty.... Besides that, asking for libraries or references to off-site resources is off topic for Stackoverflow - [help]

Comment: Actually, not empty, but, `key={} value={}` is not how you format System.out.println. Also, your Junit code says nothing about properties, so maybe fix the tests first to show what you want?

Comment: Debugged the code and it is getting values now. Key was getting set null.

Comment: Was it? The question shows `Struct{airingTo=[Struct{dow=[SATURDAY]}]}`